# Proving $\mathcal{P}(g \circ f) = \mathcal{P}(g) \circ \mathcal{P}(f)$ in a general topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I'm going through Goldblatt's "Topoi", and I'm stuck on exercise 12.5.3. There, he suggests proving that $\Omega^{g \circ f} = \Omega^g \circ \Omega^f$, where $\Omega^f$ is the morphism $f : a \rightarrow b$ lifted to act on the "powerset" $\Omega^a$ (hence $\Omega^f : \Omega^a \rightarrow \Omega^b$).

Since this doesn't seem to be a too common thing, here's how Goldblatt defines $\Omega^f$ for a given $f$:

1. Take the evaluation arrow $\text{ev}_a : \Omega^a \times a \rightarrow \Omega$. Treat it as a character of some subobject $\overline{\text{ev}_a} : \bullet \rightarrowtail \Omega^a \times a$ (we don't care about the domain, hence $\bullet$).
2. Take the image arrow $1_{\Omega^a} \times f\ [\overline{\text{ev}_a}]$, which is the monic part of the epi-monic factorization of $(1_{\Omega^a} \times f)\circ (\overline{\text{ev}_a})$. This is going to be some morphism into $\Omega^a \times b$.
3. Take the exponential adjoint of the character of this morphism and call it $\Omega^f$.

Or, graphically:

[image]

Now, I can't think of any other proof strategy except to show that $\Omega^g \circ \Omega^f$ makes the diagram defining $\Omega^{g \circ f}$ commute. Or, in other words, I'm aiming to show that $\Omega^g \circ \Omega^f$ is the exponential adjoint for $\text{char}\ 1_{\Omega^a} \times gf [\overline{\text{ev}_a}]$. How do I prove that?

The top triangle here commutes by definition of $\Omega^g$ (where $g : b \rightarrow c$), so I only need to prove that the bottom one commutes:

[image]

Here it's perhaps time to use the definition of $\text{char}$, and I was trying to prove that the top part here:

[image]

could be completed to form a pullback, hence the outer square would be pullback by the pullback lemma, hence I'll get the desired result by the $\Omega$-axiom, but all my attempts at proving that were a dead end.

Am I on the right track? What's the most straightforward way to do this exercise?

Comment: Conventionally $\Omega^{\bullet}$ is a contravariant functor but I suppose as long as the exercise is internally consistent...

Comment: This would become easy using the internal language of a topos, once you prove that the definition agrees with the interpretation of $\lambda (S : \mathcal{P}(a)) . \{ y : b \mid \exists x : a, x \in S \land f(x) = y \}$.

Comment: Or I guess in terms of powers of $\Omega$, $\lambda (S : \Omega^a) . \lambda (y : b) . \exists x : a, S(x) \land f(x) = y$.

Comment: I think another way of putting the argument you're trying to make would be in terms of Yoneda's lemma: show that there is a morphism of functors $\operatorname{Sub}({-} \times a) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times b)$ which sends a subobject of $u \times a$ to its image under $\operatorname{id}_u \times f$.  Once you show that, your $\Omega^f$ is clearly the corresponding morphism of representing objects; and you then just have to show that images in this sense "compose well".

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure I'm supposed to know about lambda calculus interpretations of internal languages of topoi according to the book structure, and neither do I know much about that. Similarly for the Yoneda's lemma, unfortunately. I can probably prove it's a valid natural transformation, but I don't know anything about "representing objects", and I'm not sure that's what's intended here.

Comment: OK, fair enough on the internal language point.  On the other hand, in my opinion, any text on topos theory which doesn't extensively use Yoneda's lemma and the corresponding way of thinking is doing a disservice to the reader -- it's really the most natural way to think about the common concepts of topos theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward proof would be to use Yoneda's lemma and the corresponding point of view.  Thus, let us start by defining a morphism of functors $f_* : \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times a) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times b)$ which takes a subobject $S$ of $u\times a$ to the image of $(\operatorname{id}_u \times f)\circ \operatorname{inc}_S \in \operatorname{Hom}(S, u \times b)$.  To see this is indeed a natural transformation is simple: if you take the epi-mono factorization of $(\operatorname{id}_u \times f) \circ \operatorname{inc}_S$, and then for $\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}(v, u)$ you take the fibered product of this factorization with $\alpha \times \operatorname{id}_b \in \operatorname{Hom}(v\times b, u\times b)$, you get an epi-mono factorization of $(\operatorname{id}_v \times f) \circ \operatorname{inc}_{\alpha^* S}$.

We can similarly define $g_* : \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times b) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times c)$ and $(g\circ f)_* : \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times a) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times c)$.  We claim that $(g\circ f)_* = g_* \circ f_*$.  To see this, suppose we have a subobject $S$ of $u \times a$.  Then by the definition of $f_*(S)$, we have an epimorphism $S \to f_*(S)$ and a monomorphism $f_*(S) \to u\times b$ which is exactly what we consider to be the canonical inclusion.  Also, by the definition of $g_*$, we have an epimorphism $f_*(S) \to g_*(f_*(S))$ and a monomorphism $g_*(f_*(S)) \to u \times c$.  Now, the composition of the two epimorphisms gives an epimorphism $S \to g_*(f_*(S))$; so by the uniqueness of epi-mono factorization, and the easy fact that $(\operatorname{id}_u \times g) \circ (\operatorname{id}_u \times f) = \operatorname{id}_u \times (g \circ f)$, we get that $(g\circ f)_*(S) = g_*(f_*(S))$ as subobjects of $u\times c$.

Now, by the Yoneda lemma, corresponding to $f_*$, $g_*$, and $(g\circ f)_*$, we have morphisms $\Omega^a \to \Omega^b$, $\Omega^b \to \Omega^c$, and $\Omega^a \to \Omega^c$.  If you look at the proof of the Yoneda lemma, it is easy to see that these corresponding morphisms give exactly $\Omega^f$, $\Omega^g$, and $\Omega^{g\circ f}$ as constructed in the problem statement.  Then, from the easy fact that the Yoneda lemma correspondence respects compositions (which might even be directly in some formulations of the Yoneda lemma), we conclude that $(g\circ f)_* = g_* \circ f_*$ implies $\Omega^{g\circ f} = \Omega^g \circ \Omega^f$.

---

Of course, as it often happens, we can fairly easily unfold the proof of the Yoneda lemma to get a direct proof.  In this case, I think it would involve taking the special case of the argument above where $u = \Omega^a$ and $S$ is the subobject of $\Omega^a \times a$ corresponding to $\operatorname{ev}_{a, \Omega} : \Omega^a \times a \to \Omega$.  If you trace through, it might also end up involving a special case of the naturality condition on $g_*$ and/or $f_*$.  However, in my opinion, using the unfolded proof would obscure the essential point of the argument above, which is that taking images of subobjects acts well with respect to compositions.

Comment: Incidentally, I think about the same mechanisms would help you to define a morphism $b^a \times \Omega^a \to \Omega^b$ and then to prove a similar composition law related to this morphism (using the canonical composition morphism $c^b \times b^a \to c^a$ and asserting the two natural morphisms $c^b \times b^a \times \Omega^a \to \Omega^c$ are equal).

Comment: I guess I kind of internalized enough of Yoneda lemma proof to make sense of what's going on here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the internal language of the topos. In fact, a very small fragment (the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus) is already enough.

The power object $PX$ is the exponential $\Omega^X$ in the topos. When $f: X\to Y$ is a morphism in the topos, then we may add it and its domain and codomain to the signature and write $$x:X\vdash f(x):Y$$
for its action. The right way to translate this is that $x$ is a code for the identity of $X$, so that $f(x) =f\circ
id_X = f$. Now the morphism $P(f)$ may be denoted as follows in the internal language.$$\phi:\Omega^Y\vdash\lambda x.\phi (f x):\Omega^X$$
A well defined interpretation procedure tells you exactly what the associated morphism in the topos is in terms of the universal properties of the involved objects. You may read about that in chapter 2 of Bart Jacobs' book *Categorical Logic and Type Theory*. It is really not that hard and you can learn it before you learn about the full internal language of a topos.

Now, assume we have to morphisms $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$. Comosition in the topos corresponds to substitution in the $\lambda$-calculus, and so we see that the composite $Pf\circ Pg$ is the interpretation of the following expression.
$$\phi: \Omega^Z\vdash \lambda x.(\lambda y.\phi (g y))(f x): \Omega^X$$
We use the typical computer science convention that $\lambda$s bind as far as they can. Now the rules of the $\lambda$-calculus (and the soundness of the interpretation with respect to those rules) tell us that this is the same morphism as the one denoted by the expression below.
$$\phi: \Omega^Z\vdash \lambda x.\phi (g(f x)): \Omega^X$$
But the interpretation of that morphism will be exactly the map $P(g \circ f)$, and that finishes the proof.

Comment: It appears you're working with the contravariant functor structure on $P$, whereas the OP's question is about the covariant functor structure on $P$.  In terms of the internal language, that's most naturally formulated using an expression involving $\exists$.  And interpreting $\exists$ is one of the most complex parts of the interpretation of the internal language, I think.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh no, that is embarrassing. I should work on my reading skills.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see what happened. I have read $\Omega^f$ and stopped thinking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Addressing that (and your comments under my question that I can't find right now), what'd you recommend to read instead/before? In fact I'm coming from the CS (or type theory-ish) side and studying topos theory to better understand what's going on when I prove things in say Agda, so I know a bit of typed lambda calculi. Jacobs is on my reading list, and I skimmed through its first few pages some time ago, but "Topoi" immediately felt more accessible to somebody with fairly low CT exposure like me, so I proceeded with the latter.

Comment: @0xd34df00d imo the best start are the two texts "categorical logic" and "notes on categorical logic" by AM Pitts. You may find them in this list. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/index.html  The next step would be the lecture notes "categoeical logic" by andrej bauer, which you can find via google. There are two versions from different years

Comment: @0xd34df00d Then you should be well equipped to understand the first four chapters of Jacobs, up to the point where they discuss first order cat. logic. They are very good and precise!

Comment: @0xd34df00d also, category theory without yoneda is a pain, so you might want to look into "categories in context" (my favourite book :) I hope it helps. I do not like Goldblatt, but that is probably a personal preference