# Covariant power object functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors

How would one go about constructing a covariant power object functor (like powerset functor in category **Set**).

Obviously, on objects, the mapping would equal
$$ A \mapsto \Omega^A. $$

But what about morphisms? I've looked about the definition of power object (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object), and the only sensible idea that came to mind is taking the diagram from the definition (I'm having trouble drawing commutative diagrams on here), replacing $r \hookrightarrow c \times d$ with $m \times \text{id}_{\Omega^d}:\text{im} f \times \Omega^d \hookrightarrow c \times \Omega^d$, where $f:d \to c$ is the morphism I want to look at, and $m$ is its image $m:\text{im} f \hookrightarrow c$.

That way i get the unique morphism $\chi_r:\Omega^d \to \Omega^c$. I'm not quite sure if that is the case, but it seems like if i get a pair $x \times X$ of the type $d \times \Omega^d$ and map it via morphism $g \times \text{id}:d \times \Omega^d \to c \times \Omega^d$, then $g(x) \in_c \chi_r(X)$ only if $g$ factors through image of $f$.

However, I fail to see the functor property of it. When trying to prove it, I only seem to be able to come to a morphism $v:\text{im}gf \to \text{im}g$, via the image property and it gets me nowhere close to $\chi_g \chi_f = \chi_{gf}$.

I wasn't able to use pullback properties, since, even though I can construct some morphisms to $\in_c$, I cannot verify the commutativity needed to produce the morphism to the pullback.

I've also looked for answers online extensively and found no positive or negative results.

Is my intuition on using the image wrong (and of so, which monomorphism should I use instead)? Or did I just miss something that can help me to prove it?

Comment: In $\mathsf{Set}$, you would have $\Omega^d \to \Omega^c$, $S \mapsto \{ y : c \mid \exists x \in S, f(x) = y \}$.  The corresponding subobject of $c \times \Omega^d$ would be $\{ (y, S) : c \times \Omega^d \mid \exists x \in S, f(x) = y \}$.  I don't think that agrees with your construction, but rather with the image of $f \times \operatorname{id} : d \times \Omega^d \to c \times \Omega^c$ composed with the subobject ${\in}_d \hookrightarrow d \times \Omega^d$.

Comment: I think another way to view that construction would be to take the morphism of functors $\operatorname{Sub}({-}\times d) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-}\times c)$ which takes a subobject of $u\times d$ to the image of $\operatorname{id}_u \times f : u\times d \to u\times c$ composed with that subobject, and then use Yoneda's lemma to get a corresponding morphism $\Omega^d \to \Omega^c$.  (Of course, you would first need to show it is indeed a natural transformation; but then, that could help with formulating why that construction is functorial.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yeah, I've written it out, and it doesn't do what I'd want it to do, you're right. How would I go about finding the right subobject? I have my doubts that using the internal logic of a topos would help, since proving the functor property will still be very hard.

Comment: Well, in the internal language, it would be almost exactly what I wrote out for the case of $\mathsf{Set}$: the interpretation of the term $S : P(d) \vdash \{ y : c \mid \exists x : d, x \in S \land f(x) = y \} : P(c)$.  And the internal logic would make it easy to prove functionality of this construction.

Comment: Otherwise, either of the constructions I wrote in the first two comments will work in a general topos.  To prove the second construction works, it could be useful to prove as a lemma that there is a covariant functor structure on $\operatorname{Sub}$ which takes a morphism $f : d \to c$ to the function which maps a subobject $d' \hookrightarrow d$ to the image of $f \circ \operatorname{inc} : d' \hookrightarrow d \to c$, as a subobject of $c$...

Comment: That proof will probably involve writing out a commutative diagram to show that $\operatorname{Sub}(f) (\operatorname{Sub}(g) (e'))$ satisfies the condition of the mono-epi factorization for $g \circ f \circ \operatorname{inc} : e' \hookrightarrow e \to d \to c$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I've tried taking $\{ (y,A) | \exists x(x \in A \land f(x) = y \} \hookrightarrow d \times \Omega^c$ and am trying to define the wanted morphism as an exponential transpose of the unique morphism $d \times \Omega^c \to \Omega$, but I got stuck. How exactly would one prove this has functor property using internal logic? I am aware of how to construct objects like this, but have never actually proven anything using internal logic, so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Just found this as a possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4655213/proving-mathcalpg-circ-f-mathcalpg-circ-mathcalpf-in-a-gene .