# How to model theories and use internal logic in a topos?

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

How would I go about modeling theories and doing math in a general topos, instead of just **Set**.

For example, in **Set**, I might define a groups as "a set which satisfies the following conditions: ..." and then work onwards from there, prove theorems and such.

Now, in a topos, there are Mitchell-Bénabou language and Kripke-Joyal semantics to model formulas, of course. I'm interested, if possible, to learn how to think in terms of topos theory. So I could take an arbitrary topos and, for example, study group theory there, by defining a group and using internal logic to prove theorems.

I assume, the definition would be more or less analogous to set-theoretic, I'd take an object $G$ and morphism $*:G \times G \to G$ and define a group $(G,*)$ such that for any generalized elements the following holds: $a,b,c:G$, $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$, there exists a generalized element $e_G:G$ such that, for any $a:G$, $e_G * a = a * e_G = a$, etc.

Now, when looking at more complicated formulas, using quantifiers and logical connectives, I should be able to use theorems about the internal logic of the topos to know that there exists an object $\{ (\vec{x}) |\varphi(\vec{x}) \}$, analogous to (sub)set of objects satisfying a formula. But how do I actually use the internal logic to describe and talk about the theories.

But for more complicated formulas, how would I prove or disprove, say, a theorem which says something about those subobjects generated by formulas? For example, if I had formulas which use morphisms and I want to prove or disprove that $\varphi_g \varphi_f = \varphi_{gf}$, similar to how one would show in **Set** that $(g \circ f)(A) = g(f(A))$, where $A$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, so $f:\mathcal{P}X \to \mathcal{P}Y$ is a function that is constructed using $f:X \to Y$?

Comment: Actually, instead of some generalized element $e_G : G$ you would usually want a *global* element $e_G \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(1, G)$.  (In this case, you end up with exactly a *group object* of the topos $\mathcal{T}$.  But in the topos case, what's interesting is for example that given a subobject $A$ of a group object $G$, you can define something which deserves to be called "the subgroup of $G$ generated by $A$", by using the internal language essentially to define it as the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $A$.)

Comment: In general, the internal logic satisfies typed versions of the standard rules of natural deduction.  For example, ${\exists}E$ would read: suppose $\phi$ is some formula with a possibly free variable $x$ such that $\Gamma, x : A \vdash \phi : \Omega$, and $\psi$ is some formula without $x$ free such that $\Gamma \vdash \psi : \Omega$.  Also suppose $\Gamma \vdash (\exists x:A, \phi)\mathrm{~true}$ and $\Gamma, x : A, \phi \mathrm{~true} \vdash \psi \mathrm{~true}$.  Then $\Gamma \vdash \psi \mathrm{~true}$.  (And this rule is easy to prove from the Kripke-Joyal semantics of $\exists$.)

Comment: Incidentally, is this question related to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805316/covariant-power-object-functor ?

Answer (score 0):

The following does not answer your specific question about subobjects generated by formulae, but gives you a reference on how to go about taking an arbitrary topos and using proving theorems about objects internally.

I learned how to do this from the book [Toposes and Local Set Theories](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486462862) by J. L. Bell -- a $1 copy that was cased (bound) upside down, which led to some fun conversations when I read it on the bus.

The first three chapters cover everything you technically need to work internally, including an inference system for the local language, and the semantics that interprets it inside any topos. Chapter 7 explains how to deduce basic properties of $\mathbb{N}$ in a topos with a natural numbers object.

Depending on your background, the intuitionistic nature of the internal logic might cause you more trouble than using the internal language itself. To prove non-trivial results about e.g. group objects, you may have to either supplement your studies with a textbook on constructive algebra, or stick to working in Boolean topoi such as [$G$-$\mathrm{Set}$s](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+G-sets).